# Doxygen (C++) missing "Function Documentation" for global functions in namespace

Tags: c++, doxygen

All,

I have the following c++ header file, and the "Function Documentation" section for function `bar` appears only if I commented out the namespace `foo`.  If the namespace is there, I do get the "Functions" section, but there is no "Function Documentations" section.

I am documenting the namespace and the file.  I cannot update the Doxygen file (and EXTRACT_ALL is NO).

Is there a way to make "Function Documentation" appear with the function in the namespace?

Thanks.

```
/**
 * @brief Namespace foo 
 */
namespace foo {

/**
 * @file    test.hh
 *
 * @brief   My brief
 *
 * @details My details
 */

/**
 * @brief   My function
 *
 * @details My details
 */
void function bar( int dummy ) {

}

}
```